# Bluetoothctl from script with submenu

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I m just trying to prepare script which emulate BLE Peripheral Device. I am using bluetoothctl like this:

```
bluetoothctl -- power on 
bluetoothctl -- advertise on
```

Above scripts works properly, but I don't know how to call submenu of bluetoothctl advertise(you can see it if you call help) from my script init.sh, something like this

```
bluetoothctl -- menu advertise, name Rasbperry, name on
```

Any suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

When using `bluetoothctl` you don't need to use the `menu` command, you can specify the command hierachally. For example `advertise.name Rasbperry` and `advertise.name on`.

One word of caution about using `bluetoothctl` in this way; it is not a published API and the commands do change from time to time.

The published BlueZ API is available at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

There is an example advertisement at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-advertisement

And a peripheral at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
bluetoothctl << EOF
menu scan
version
quit
EOF
```

then

```
bluetoothctl << EOF
menu advertise
name Raspberry
name on
...
quit
EOF
```

Using variable for the name:

```
MYNAME="Raspberry"

bluetoothctl << EOF
menu advertise
name ${MYNAME}
name on
...
quit
EOF
```